# Problematic nested subscript

Tags: subscripts, nesting

Hello and sorry if I'm reiterating an already asked question. The two i-subscripts have different positions in relation to m, the one on the right hand side of the inequality being the correct one presumably. Is there any way to fix this?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\dim_{\mathbb{F}_{2^{m_{i}}}} W \geq \frac{n}{m_i}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx please always post complete (small) documents showing all packages used. You can use the image upload button but remove (just) the `!` in the generated markup: that will make a link to your image, someone with edit rights will put the `!` back.

Comment: This is by design: the `m` in the left is smaller than the `m` in the right, so the output is a bit wider to enhance readability. But please don't use this sub-super-sub-superscript notation! It's not readable anyway ...

Comment: I'll upload the image, it looks OK to me, subsubscripts are set in a more cramped style b default

Comment: I want to say something about the dimension of W as a vector space over the finite field with 2^{m_i} elements. I don't see any way around it, unless I use awkward abbreviated notation of some sort.

Comment: You could force the superscriot to be set in textstyle (and so the sub-superscript in subscriptstyle but I'm not sure that would look better, I think you just accept that that is a choice of the font designer (Knuth in this case) and leave it that way or try another font set.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll put \! before the i's. It's not ideal, but it looks less bad than it does now.

Comment: @StefanosAivazidis If your fields are always finite with characteristic 2, you could simply use `\mathbb{F}(m_i)`, after defining this symbol.

Comment: You could try a field extension type notation such as `\( \dim(W:\mathbb F_{2^{m_i}}) \)` to reduce one level of subscripts.  You could also use `m(i)` throughout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, when a font is scaled to a lower point size, the glyphs can change to retain legibility.  However, your unhappiness over the relation of the `i` and `m` indicates you don't like the choices made by the font.

Originally I used the `scalerel` package to take a `normalsize` `m_i` and scale it down to an appropriate size, but then Hendrik Vogt pointed out that the same could be more simply accomplished using a `\scalebox{0.6}{$m_i$}` for the sub-sub-superscript, since `\usebox` does not apply the `\mathpalette` wrapper.

The `\scalebox` creates the subscripted `m_i` to be an exact scale of the normal size `m_i`.  Of course, the drawback is that, when scaled down, the strokes become thinner, and some may consider that more detrimental to the appearance that the relation of the `i` to the `m`.  In any event, here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\dim_{\mathbb{F}_{2^{%
\scalebox{0.6}{$m_i$}%
}}} W \geq \frac{n}{m_i}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I *strongly* advise against using these *four-level* sub- and superscripts. Using two levels is OK, three levels is already dubious. In my opinion, the major problem in the output is *not* the distance between `m` and the index `i` but the fact that the `\mathbb{F}` and the `m` are almost on the same level. This way it almost looks like the product of `\mathbb{F}_2` and `m_i`. If you *really* want to do it, here are some manual tweaks:

[image: output with manual tweaks]

I pushed the index `2` further down by adding an empty superscript to the `\mathbb{F}`, and I reduced the horizontal space at three places, most notably before the `W`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\dim_{\mathbb{F}^{}_{\mkern-1mu 2^{m_{\mkern-1mu i}}}} \mkern-5mu W$
\end{document}
```

However, the better option is to use the recommendations from the comments to the question, e.g., to define `\mathbb{F}(m_i)` or `\mathbb{F}(2,m_i)` as a notation for the finite field with `2^{m_i}` elements.